# git@github.com ref not getting converted to git@ssh.github.com

Tags: git, github, ssh, pip, github-actions

I want to use port 443 in my github action to install a private repo using deploy keys, the below code works fine when there is `git@ssh.github.com` in package name.

```
      - name: Try pip install 443
        run: |
          ssh-keyscan -p 443 -t rsa ssh.github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -p 443"
          
          pip install git+ssh://git@ssh.github.com/my-org/my-repo.git@v1.0.0#subdirectory=core-utils
```

But the users will add dependencies with `git@github.com` and not `git@ssh.github.com`. So I want to convert any reference of `git@github.com` to `git@ssh.github.com` as ssh with port 443 requires it, but the below code doesn't work

```
      - name: Try pip install 443
        run: |
          ssh-keyscan -p 443 -t rsa ssh.github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -p 443"
          git config --global url."ssh://git@ssh.github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"
          git config --list
          
          pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/my-org/my-repo.git@v1.0.0#subdirectory=core-utils
```

and fails with

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
  Connection closed by 140.82.113.3 port 443
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong with `git config --global url."ssh://git@ssh.github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"` ?

Comment: What else is in the SSH logs?

Answer (score 0):

git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -p 443"

That says always use port 443 for ssh commands.

If you remove rust line hit will use the standard ssh which will use port 22

Comment: I already have `git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -p 443"` in both the snippets, my question is why *git@github.com* not being converted to *git@ssh.github.com*

Comment: Your connecting to a HTTPS port with that option, remove it, its using ssh but ssh to port 443

Comment: I'm following this, can't use 22, https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port